# Is it possible to mutate an array inside of a class function in SwiftUI/Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, mutation

If I have declared an array inside a class, is it possible to mutate that array from one of the class's functions? I was hoping there was some equivalent for the 'mutating' keyword that can be used for classes:

```
class className: ObservableObject {
    @Published var arrayName: [arrayType] = []

    func mutateArray(address: String) {
        self.arrayName = []
        let geocoder = Geocoder(accessToken: 'accessTokenHere')
        geocoder.geocode(ForwardGeocodeOptions(query: address) { (placemarks, attribution, error) in 
        guard let placemarks = placemarks
        else {
            return
        }
        self.arrayName = [value1, value2, value3]
        //This only updates the array inside this closure/context. Is there any way to have the update persist after the function has ended?
    }
}
```

Comment: As soon as you name property `var` in class it is mutatable from inside class, because it is reference type, so it 'just works'. Therefore would you show problem code instead?

Comment: This code should work... so something else is broken elsewhere

Comment: SwiftUI is a user-interface framework, like UIKit. Your question is about basic Swift programming, however. It's important to know the difference. I see a lot of people here use the terms Swift and SwiftUI interchangeably, which I suspect confuses a lot of beginners.

Comment: @bsod Ah, alright. I removed the swiftui tag

Comment: No worries, just an FYI 

Comment: @Asperi  I realize now that my code was pretty generic. If it makes a difference, the array is wrapped with Published and the array update takes place inside a closure in the function. The updated code is now in the question above^

Answer (score 2):

Classes don't need an equivalent for `mutating` because it is a reference type, unlike structs which is value type which is why it requires `mutating` functions. Try this code on your Xcode-playground:

```swift
import Foundation

class className {
    var arrayName: [String] = []

    func mutateArray() {
        arrayName = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
    }
}
let object = className()
print(object.arrayName)
object.mutateArray()
print(object.arrayName)
```

Comment: I need the update to persist after the function is called though...also, the code I had before was way too generic so if you scroll back up to the top you can see what it looks like (I can't use mutating)

Answer (score 0):

The published properties should be updated on main queue, so do the following

```
class ClassName: ObservableObject {
    @Published var arrayName: [arrayType] = []

    func mutateArray(address: String) {
        self.arrayName = []
        let geocoder = Geocoder(accessToken: 'accessTokenHere')
        geocoder.geocode(ForwardGeocodeOptions(query: address) { [weak self] (placemarks, attribution, error) in
            guard let placemarks = placemarks
                else {
                    return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {     // << here !!
                self?.arrayName = [value1, value2, value3] // << weak for safety
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it works, but how should I test it to make sure it works? Because it waits for everything else to finish before it executes the array update, right?

Comment: @nickcoding, what do you mean by "waits for everything else to finish"? I'd say it does not way just reschedules update from any working queue, which is usually is background, to main queue, which is the only queue to be used for UI.

Comment: I'm just kind of unsure about how asnychronuos waits work and need to look into them. Also, the above code doesn't work (the array's value isn't persisting after the function finishes)...if I print out the results after this function has been executed, the array's value is [ ]...

Comment: @nickcoding, asynchronous does not wait, so you should nothing print at the end of this function, instead callback close will be call when `geocode` function is finished, so results should be printed at the end of closure, and that's why there should be redirection from closure back to main thread. Play with it - async is fun.

Comment: Well...I need the changes to the array to persist after the function is over but they aren't...the array is only being updated inside the closure and then once the closure is left, it reverts back to having the value [ ]